# Safari Extension and (extension) reload button suddenly not working

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I've got a simple test extension that just pops up with an alert.

The problem is that the extension (which is installed) isn't working at all. The 'reload' button in the extension builder isn't functioning either, even though it was 5 minutes ago. I've restarted Safari multiple times, but to no avail.

Any idea what on earth is happening here?

Comment: Maybe there's somewhere semicolon missing? Inspect your JS code on possible syntax errors.

Comment: The thing is, this problem started without any code changes. If there's anything wrong with my code, it'll appear when the page is loaded, not when I try and reload the extension in the extension builder.

Comment: did your safari dev certificate expire?